# Did netty.3.5.7 begin initializing worker pool with 200 threads?

Tags: threadpool, netty

Can anyone confirm if Netty 3.5.7 introduced a change that causes an NIO threadpool of 200 threads to be created?

We have a webapp that we're running in Tomcat 7 and I've noticed that at some point there is a new block of 200 NIO threads - all labeled "New I/O Worker #".  I've verified that with 3.5.6, this threadpool is not initialized with 200 threads, but only a boss thread.  As soon as I replaced the the jar with 3.5.7, I now have 200 NIO threads + the boss thread.

If this change was introduced with 3.5.7, is it possible to control the pool size with some external configuration?  I ask because we don't explicitly use Netty, it's used by a 3rd party JAR.

Thanks,
Bob

Answer (score 0):

Netty switched to not lazy start workers anymore because of the overhead of synchronization. I guess that could be the problem you see.

The only help here is to change the worker-count when create the Nio*ChannelFactory. 200 is a way to high anyway.

Comment: how does 4.0 handle this?  does it default to a smaller size?  If the prototype stuff works out, we'll be using 4.0 when we start using netty directly

Comment: It is the same as 3.x in that respect. Be aware that 4.x API is not compatible with 3.x .